# "Unfortunately (my app) has Stopped" error when trying to run my application

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

(Home.java), I am trying to create a loading screen that eventually leads to this page (Home.java.)

```
package com.androidpeople.splash;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class VirtualSkiInstructor extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("Main Activity");
        setContentView(textView);
    }
}
```

Loading Screen (SplashScreen.java). This is the code that creates the Splash Screen, and the loading page

```
package com.androidpeople.splash;

import your.custom.splash.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.splash);

final int welcomeScreenDisplay = 3000;
/** create a thread to show splash up to splash time */
Thread welcomeThread = new Thread() {

    int wait = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            super.run();

                                        while (wait < welcomeScreenDisplay) {
                    sleep(100);
                    wait += 100;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("EXc=" + e);
            } finally {

                startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                VirtualSkiInstructor.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    welcomeThread.start();

}
}
```

(splash.xml)

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:gravity="center" android:background="#6B8AAD">
 <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="18sp"
 android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#fff"></TextView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

(strings.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Compass</string>
    <string name="app_name">Compass</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below code to add VirtualSkiInstructor activity into your manifest file.

```
<activity
    android:name=".VirtualSkiInstructor"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add VirtualSkiInstructor Activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<activity android:name=".VirtualSkiInstructor"> </activity>
```